# Generate a rails migration directly on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, migration

I have some sort of snafu that happened where an intern accidentally uploaded a bit of code to our staging site and then cancelled.  Now, there is a page on the staging site that requires a migration that doesn't exist on the staging site.

I'm relatively new to this as well and I'm wondering what the best way to add a migration for that missing column directly to the staging site.  Is it

1. Pull the code, add the migration, push the code (which changes the
   staging from the dev, as the dev has the master.
2. Generate the migration in some other way in heroku directly?

I honestly don't even know if the way we think this error happened is actually the truth.  I just have to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your migration existed you can rollback on directly on heroku in activity onglet.

or

1. Pull your repo
2. Add your migration
3. Push it on heroku
4. Run `heroku run rake db:migrate --app your_staging_app`

Comment: I am marking this as true as it is a good answer for this problem and normally would be the answer.  What really happened was another developer pushed and didn't run migrations.

Comment: If you have CI (for exemple circle ci), after deploy on heroku, CI run automatically heroku run rake db:migrate. With this solution over migration problem :)